# Calling column variable for ggplot2 getting Error in eval(): object 'value' not found

Tags: r, object, ggplot2, eval

I have the following data 'test_1' as defined below:

```
test_1 <- structure(list(word = c("five", "hand", "book", "glasses"),
                author = c("Asimov", "Asimov", "Bradbury", "Logan"),
                proportion = c( .05, .03, .10, .08)), 
                row.names = c(NA, -4L), 
                .Names = c("word", "author", "proportion"), 
                class = c("data.frame"))
```

Applying this to ggplot2 code I got from http://tidytextmining.com/:

```
ggplot(test_1, aes(x = proportion, y = `Asimov`,color = abs(`Asimov` - proportion))) +
      geom_abline(color = "gray40", lty = 2) +
      geom_jitter(alpha = 0.1, size = 2.5, width = 0.3, height = 0.3) +
      geom_text(aes(label = word), check_overlap = TRUE, vjust = 1.5) +
      scale_x_log10(labels = percent_format()) +
      scale_y_log10(labels = percent_format()) +
      scale_color_gradient(limits = c(0, 0.001), low = "darkslategray4", high = "gray75") +
      facet_wrap(~author, ncol = 2) +
      theme(legend.position="none") +
      labs(y = "Asimov", x = NULL)
```

But I get this error: Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Asimov' not found.

I'm pretty sure that this is related to the way the y in the aes() is calling a value from the "author" column in test_1, but I cannot find any other questions that get to this point; or I'm way off base.

I was able to get this to work once using column names and values matching the published example, but I cannot replicate it anymore and I do not know why. In that case I was using made up data matching the format of the published example, which is the same as test_1, but much larger than needed for this question.

The same error occurs for this code which did also work once upon a time:

```
 cor.test(data = test_1[test_1$author == "Asimov",],
     ~ proportion + `Bradbury`)
```

Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: You don't have a column named Asimov in your dataframe, yet you map it to an aesthetic in your ggplot. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Generally you map aesthetics to _columns_, which in this case would be `y = author` (no quotes!). Are you trying to graph only a subset of your data or something?

Comment: I believe that the purpose of defining the author name is to generate a comparison between the words from the named author and the other authors. Basically the named author defines the 1:1 abline and the words from the other authors are plotted against this line, the closer the word to the line the greater the relationship between words.